# onMouseOver for span inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a MouseOver for the #AboutButton.  But the alert does not pop up.  Any clue to why and how to do it.

--js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#AboutButton').mouseover(function() {
 alert('test');  
});



});
```

--html code

```
 <div id="Menu">
    <span id="HomeButton">Home</span>
    <span id="ButtonSeparator01">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="AboutButton">About</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Working here bruv: http://jsfiddle.net/m5sE2/

Comment: Works great in chrome and firefox

Comment: hmm...I am on linux/chrome.. This is straight forward, I wonder why it is not working.

Comment: @Jean hope you have no spelling mistake in your script source? jus an idea :P

Comment: @Tats_innit none, because I just copy/paste the code into jsfiddle..
Could you put your first comment as an answer for me to accept.

Comment: @Jean Sure would love to; gimme 2 min! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/m5sE2/ (copying as we discussed in the comments above)

Have a nice one bruv!

**jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#AboutButton').mouseover(function() {
 alert('test');  
});



});​
```